Get the Shopify CustomerVisit / Session ID via Liquid Objects
Shopify stores what appears to be a time bound session id under the _shopify_s cookie (Documentation: https://www.shopify.com/legal/cookies#shopify-s-websites)
They describe it as follows

Used to identify a given browser session/shop combination. Duration is 30 minute rolling expiry of last use.

Based on my understanding, this is equivalent to a CustomerVisit id from their GraphQL docs.
I would like to access this value in a liquid template.
It works to do this under a script tag:
const getCookie = () => return "placeholder for logic to get a cookie";
const shopifySessionID = getCookie('_shopify_s');

I'd prefer to do something like this, which works for the customer id:
const customerId = {{ customer.id }}
console.log("customerId", customerId)

Is this supported in Liquid Objects? Is there another alternative?

Shopify does not expose session-related data like the _shopify_s cookie or session ID via Liquid objects directly. Liquid objects are primarily designed to access store, customer, product, and order-related data, but they do not provide direct access to session or cookie data, such as CustomerVisit IDs or the _shopify_s cookie.
So, as an alternative approach, you will need to rely on JavaScript to read the cookie value. And then, you can combine this with Liquid by injecting relevant customer or product data where needed, but the actual session ID retrieval must be handled client-side via JavaScript.
In the theme.liquid file, you can add the below script and adjust it as you need:
<script>
  const customerId = {{ customer.id | json }};
  console.log('Customer ID:', customerId);

  function getCookie(name) {
    const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
  }

  const shopifySessionID = getCookie('_shopify_s');
  console.log('Shopify Session ID:', shopifySessionID);
</script>


